# Visual Studio 2017 - Packages fail to install when I create Web Application (.NET Framework) project MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Whenever I create a new ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) project and I choose the MVC template, I get this message:

> Could not add all required packages to the project. The following packages failed to install from 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio Shared Packages'

- Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1: Unable to find version '11.0.1' of package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
- bootstrap.3.3.7: Unable to find version '3.3.7' of package 'bootstrap'.
- jQuery.3.3.1: Unable to find version '3.3.1' of package 'jQuery'.
- Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.4: Unable to find version '3.2.4' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor'.
- Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3: Unable to find version '1.1.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization'.
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.4: Unable to find version '3.2.4' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages'.
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0: Unable to find version '1.0.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure'.
- Microsoft.AspNet.MVC.5.2.4: Unable to find version '5.2.4' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.MVC'.
- Modernizr.2.8.3: Unable to find version '2.8.3' of package 'Modernize'.
- Antlr.3.5.0.2: Unable to find version '3.5.0.2' of package 'Antlr'.
- WebGrease.1.6.0: Unable to find version '1.6.0' of package 'WebGrease'.
- jQuery.Validation.1.17.0: Unable to find version '1.17.0' of package 'jQuery.Validation'
- Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation.3.2.4: Unable to find version 3.2.4 of package 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation'.

Then after clicking "Ok", I get another message:

> Unable to find version '2.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform'.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling my Visual Studio but it didn't help.

***Update***
VS2017 released a new update today, I updated to the new version 15.9.27 from version 15.9.26 and it fixed half of my errors. The errors I'm left with now are the following:

- bootstrap.3.3.7: Unable to find version '3.3.7' of package 'bootstrap'
- Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.4: Unable to find version '3.2.4' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor'.
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.4: Unable to find version '3.2.4' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages'.
- Microsoft.AspNet.MVC.5.2.4: Unable to find version '5.2.4' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.MVC'.
- Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation.3.2.4: Unable to find version 3.2.4 of package 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation'.

Comment: "C:\Program Files OxB6" looks broken to me (for a couple of reasons). Do you actually have a folder called that? First, It looks like it's trying to be one of the standard folders which are "C:\Program Files" and "C:\Program Files (x86)". Second, it's almost a hex byte, but that would be prefixed by a 0 (zero), not an O (oh).

Comment: A couple things. (1) Do you have to use ancient VS2017? That is many years behind the improved VS2019. (2) Eliminate VS2017 artifacts first. Get out of VS2017 completely. Start a VS2017 Developer Cmd window. "cd" to your project or solution directory. Nuke the obj and bin directories. Do a "msbuild /t:restore". Does it restore the packages it is looking for? Yes, "0xB6" in the path name is bogus.

Comment: @itsme86 I scanned the screenshot with an image scanner and it misread "(x86)" and put "OxB6", my bad I just corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to install the visual studio, there itself it asks for the things to be installed like web application,azure functions etc. I believe you have missed the .net framework with web application development to be checked for installing.

Comment: I had all of them checked, also made sure to check all the framework versions.